# Getting Internal server in sub folder pages

Tags: directory, internal-server-error

I have just created sub folder called "blog", so access link is `example.com/blog`.

I have installed WordPress in blog folder, configure database and all but when access above link then I am getting error called

> **Internal Server Error**
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I am using godaddy server ,Also I have checked for `.htaccess` file but there is not `.htaccess` file created for main domain. Should I need to create separate `.htaccess` for sub folder "blog" to solve this error?

If yes then what code I need to put in `.htaccess` for sub folder internal server error remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create .htaccess file.
Create .htaccess file and paste below code in it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: May I need to add : Options +FollowSymLinks  at top? in .htaccess?

Comment: no need to add anything

Comment: Okay..Let me add.

Comment: Blog is working but all post redirects to not found page.

Comment: have you upload already created database ?

Comment: no..new post created. is there any change require in .htaccess related to "not found" page? redirecT?

Comment: try with permalink setting,set as post name. and then check all thing again